# Is there a way to Controle the IDRAC Console through scripts

Tags: shell-scripting

is there a way to Controle the IDRAC Console through scripts, i.e. say if i am installing OS on Bare Metal Server and i only have IDRAC as a source and want to select the OPtion 1 or 2 or 3, instead of manually pressing/entering 1,2 or 3 is there any way that we can control that through Scripts(Perl, Python.. etc)

i am working on a project where we have to automate the installation of Hypervisor on a bare metal server and we need to write a script for the same to interact to the IDRAC 7 Console.

Comment: have you tried sshing to the idrac ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand which options you're looking for but
You can jump inside IDRAC by SSH (before enable it) make some commands the like these:

```
show   [<options>] [<target>] [<properties>] 
       [<propertyname>== <propertyvalue>]
set    [<options>] [<target>] <propertyname>=<value>
cd     [<options>] [<target>]
create [<options>] <target> [<property of new target>=<value>] 
       [<property of new target>=<value>]
delete [<options>] <target>
exit   [<options>]
reset  [<options>] [<target>]
start  [<options>] [<target>]
stop   [<options>] [<target>]
version [<options>]
help   [<options>] [<help topics>]
load -source <URI> [<options>] [<target>]
dump -destination <URI> [<options>] [<target>]
```

I don't know if yours IDRAC has modern firmware with more options, but mine are just few.
Otherwise you can pass some parameters using set directive , this is the reference manual by cli.
http://cfdlab.unsw.wikispaces.net/file/view/dell-poweredge-drac7-1.50.50-command-line.pdf
I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot.. But i am trying to interact through GUI i.e. IDRAC Virtual Console For Eg. on Bare Metal Server while Installing OS i may have to Select Windows 2003 , Can i Control selecting the OS through Script/RACADM commands. Another example is say i to Format C: to select the C: and Fomat Button can i use any Shell Script?.... Overall Can i control the Virtual Console through any scripts?

Comment: using the guy?? something like this https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/
But you need to dedicate a windows machine for this.
:-)

Comment: Sure Frank, We can dedicate the Windows Machine for it, but will that really work? i mean can we interacte the IDRAC Console through this Autoit? We will be able to Create different Vd's and other Stuff?

Comment: I build 25 scripts on a simply XP windows machine, this scripts works from 3 years in order to reboot 25 cisco Access points every morning , because those devices didn't have SSH access (my customer had a few budget).
It works fine believe me!

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Will try and surly tell the results thanks much

Comment: You're welcome .... remember you can use also a recorder for make less code.
Please accept my answer if you can.